# Centos: there is no ~/.cache/upstart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, environment-variables, dbus

I'm new with linux.As I know `~/.cache/upstart` is folder where system processes log their stuff. But I can't find this folder in Centos. What I'm most curious about is that on Ubuntu this folder contains `dbus-session.conf` where it logs dbus connection name(value of env variable `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`). Could you please tell me where I can fid this folder, or name itself?(I know how to get this env variable by `/proc/$pid/environ` but I want to do it by this way.) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upstart` is something that was never in the RHEL stream, so you won't find much about that on a CentOS system.

Following the guidance on [this link](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Tips_and_tricks-Configuring_a_VNC_Server.html) there is another option for setting that variable.  `dbus-launch` will print out the shell variables for you, so you could just do

```
 . <(dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session)
```

to source the output of that command and have it set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` (and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID`) for you.

This seems to work on both Fedora and Ubuntu, and I see the `dbus-launch` executable available for my CentOS 6 machine in the base repo, so I assume it'll work there too.

(On CentOS `yum whatprovides '*/dbus-launch'` says it's in the `dbus-x11` package.)

Comment: thank you so much, but could you please tell me if dbus logs the name of connection(session) in any file?

Comment: @user590536 So my solution may not really be quite right as I started trying to dig more.  That will create a new dbus session (as I should have expected from the "launch" part).  You might get some good reading on this stuff from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28463/run-a-dbus-program-in-crontab-how-to-know-about-the-session-id.  I had been starting to play with various `dbus-send` options, but it doesn't look straightforward to get what you're asking for I fear, at least not to my novice to dbus ways